# AngularJS: Reload a Child View

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm relatively new to AngularJS and have been scouring SO for a few days now and beginning to pull my hair out.

Imagine a two pane page. The left side being the parent view and the right side being the child view. The child view contents are based on which child view is selected in the Left Side parent view.

When I first load the page, my parent view loads correctly (it presents a list of its clickable children utilizing ui-sref). The child view is empty because the URL isn't fully populated, only '/parent'; it doesn't yet have a 'child' state. That is fine.

The first time I click on a child, the state changes from '/parent' to '/parent/child1' and it loads the child view with 'child1' data beautifully - just the way I want it to.

BUT THEN, no matter what other Child I click on within the Parent view, my child view does not reload/refresh; it stays with 'child1' data. But the URL changes based on the newly clicked 'child' path. So if I click 'child9' the url changes to '/parnet/child9' but 'child1' data persists.

If I refresh and start over again and choose 'child2' it'll still work beautifully as well, loading 'child2' data without being able to load 'child9' - same problem.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried my best to write this for any others in the same predicament.

From index.html:

```
  <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <li ng-repeat="child in childs" ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="parent.child({child:child.filter})">
    {{child.name}}

  <div ng-controller="ChildController">
    <li ng-repeat="childData in childData">
    {{childData}}
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope,) {
// This controller presents a list of the parent's children that are clickable 

app.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'ChildService', function($rootScope, $state, $scope, $stateParams, ChildService) {
// This controller presents contents of the child
```

Services:

```
app.service('ParentService', function($rootScope){
// This service returns Parent Data from third party, in this case Firebase.

app.service('ChildService', function($stateParams){
    var child = $stateParams.child;
// This service returns Child Data from third party, in this case Firebase.
```

From App.js:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('parent', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/parent',
            templateUrl: 'home/parent.html',
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('parent.child', {
            url: '/{child}',
            templateUrl: 'home/child.html'
        })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you got a good start to asking good questions here, much better than most.  It still wouldn't hurt to give the tour page a look (go to help: tour).

Comment: AngularJS version? And welcome :)

Comment: where is your ui-view in the HTML? probably best is to have 2 ui-view and populate each one fo the in the state.

Comment: Tally, I currently have one main ui-view that encompasses both panes. The two ui-views makes sense to me. And to be honest, to learn AngularJS, I'm modifying a template to build out my solution. So one ui-view is a derivative of the original author.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the recommendation. Will do!

Comment: Frank, there's not really enough here to reproduce your problem and help out. It's pure chance that I see the answer here because there is one extra line in your services comments. In the future, please make sure you include relevant parts; see [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Kato, thanks for taking the time to respond. You're right. What I omitted contained my error - which was a simple, misplaced function. Thanks for the guidance on MCVE going forward.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, services and factories are singletons--they are only invoked once and whatever you return is the service. Your CHildService and ParentService are only invoked the first time you load a corresponding page.

Instead, you want to do something like this:

```
app.service('ChildService', function(){
  // return a function that can be called with each page load
  return function(childId) {
     // I have no idea what this service returns, so I'm just making something up
     return listOfChildren[childId];
  }
});

app.controller('ChildController', function($scope, $stateParams, ChildService) {
   // get the child based on the CURRENT value of child query parameter
   $scope.child = ChildService($stateParams.child);
});
```